How to allow from domain.com fetch to domain.com:PORT
I have working cert on my domain.com
also working example for my kurento web client  on domain.com:2020
Both running by Nodejs:
(npm run site) domain.com:443  standard port
(npmm run openvidu/kurento client)  domain.com:2020
Cert are same for both.
Now i wanna use services from domain.com:2020 on my  normal link domain.com/MY_CHAT.html
error log :
   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any suggestion.

The error occurs because browsers block mixed-content requests (HTTP on a different port like 2020) when using HTTPS. You need to proxy the requests from domain.com:2020 through domain.com using the same HTTPS port (443) or configure your server to serve everything on 443.

I forgot to put in openvidu node :
// NOT SECURED * 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
  // res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

Same code i alredy have on domain.com node server code.

Add this to the question, you can edit it!
